# Identify a USB Setup packet

Tags: usb, microcontroller, firmware

How is a a SETUP request distinguished from a normal data OUT packet from the host? 
(As the INT/OUT data packet format is always "Sync PID Data CRC16 EOP")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PID field has a value that identifies it as a setup packet.

See http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb3.shtml#USBProtocols